# Move entire row when sorting column (Google Apps Script)

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a list of names in Column B, and a bunch of data (ID number, bank account details, etc.) in columns C:AK that corresponds/belongs to the name in column B.

I want to sort column B alphabetically, but the entire rows data must move with the name when sorted.

E.g. Lets say **Ted** is in **B2** and **Amy** is in **B3**. When I do `myrange.sort(2)`, Ted will now move to **B3**, but **C2:AK2** must also now become **C3:AK3**. Otherwise **Amy**'s personal details will now show up in the same row as **Ted**.

Does that make sense?

*Example code:*

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Summary');
var curRange = sheet.getRange("B2:B6");
curRange.sort(2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your range only contains a single column so naturally, calling the 'sort()' method ignores all other columns in the sheet. You should select the entire data range and then sort by the selected column

```
 var sortRange = sheet.getRange("B2:AK");
 sortRange.sort({column:2, ascending: true});
```